# The code signature version is no longer supported on latest version of everything

Tags: swift, xcode, code-signing-certificate

Why does my app not install or run on my devices?  I keep getting the error, "The code signature version is no longer supported."  I am running the latest versions of everything and have tried everything I could find so far on this site about correcting the problem.

Things I've tried:
-Removing all unnecessary libraries except Firebase and SDWebImage
-Removing all package dependencies except the above two and Updating the packages.
-Adding --generate-entitlement-der to "Other Code Signing Flags" in Build Settings
-Removing all code provisioning profiles and signing certificates and generating new ones
-Automatic signing and manual signing
-Reset package caches
-Cleaning the build folder
-Uploading to GitHub/cloning/building the app from the clone.
-my iPhone and iPad devices (the app runs in the simulator, although I haven't been using the simulator because I'm having issues with Firebase login.)

System specs:
macOS 12.5
XCode Version 13.4.1 (13F100)
iOS version 15.6

The error message:

```
Details

Unable to install "SoulandForm"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620375
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2022-08-07 21:31:46 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
}
--
The code signature version is no longer supported.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620375
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 261622;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8008029)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000110d779d1 DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 220
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000110db3ce7 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 155
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010460d7d6 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 71
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000110db3a1d -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1422
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x0000000120054668 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.301 + 3414
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010473f3d4 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001047404bc __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 372
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff8148490cc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff81484a317 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff814850317 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 672
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff814850dfd _dispatch_lane_invoke + 366
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff81485aeee _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 753
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff8149fdfd0 _pthread_wqthread + 326
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff8149fcf57 start_wqthread + 15
);
}
--

Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "iPad11,6";
    "device_osBuild" = "15.5 (19F77)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 11202;
    "operation_errorCode" = "-402620375";
    "operation_errorDomain" = "com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain";
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDEiPhoneRunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_consoleMode" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 5;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_runnable_swiftVersion" = "5.6.1";
    "param_runnable_type" = 2;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphoneos15.5";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "15.5";
    "sdk_variant" = iphoneos;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 12.5 (Build 21G72)
Xcode 13.4.1 (20504) (Build 13F100)
Timestamp: 2022-08-07T17:31:46-04:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this!  It turns out that some of the Firebase libraries were causing this error.  I stripped it down to the most bare bones of what I needed from them and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I turned a framework from "Embed & Sign" to "Do Not Embed" to solve my problem.

Comment: That framework is a static framework, and does not need to be embeded.